# What does "no match for 'operator >>'" mean in my code?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, structure

I'm trying to look for what is wrong in this fragment of code. It says the error : `[Error] no match for 'operator>>' in 'inputData >> Player[i].AthleteType::firstName`' for the line:

```
inputData >> Player[i].firstName;
```

Can someone tell me what this means? And also if this is the right way to read data from a file that looks like this:

```
Peter Gab 2653 Kenya 127
Usian Bolt 6534 Jamaica 128
Other Name 2973 Bangladesh -1
Bla Bla 5182 India 129
Some Name 7612 London -1



//this is the structure
struct AthleteType
{
    string firstName[SIZE];
    string lastName[SIZE];
    int athleteNumber[SIZE];
    string country[SIZE];
    int athleteTime[SIZE];
};


void readInput(int SIZE)
{
    AthleteType Player[SIZE];

    ifstream inputData("Athlete info.txt");

    int noOfRecords=0;

    for (int i=0; i < SIZE; i++, noOfRecords++)
    {
        inputData >> Player[i].firstName; 
        inputData >> Player[i].lastName;
        inputData >> Player[i].athleteNumber;
        inputData >> Player[i].country;
        inputData >> Player[i].athleteTime;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < noOfRecords; i++)
    {
        cout << "First Name: " << Player[i].firstName << endl;
        cout << "Last Name: " << Player[i].lastName << endl;
        cout << "Athlete Number: " << Player[i].athleteNumber << endl;
        cout << "Country: " << Player[i].country << endl;
        cout << "Athlete Time: " << Player[i].athleteTime << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @StoryTeller JF is trying to input to a string array.

Comment: Shouldn't this `inputData >> Player[i].firstName;` be `inputData >> Player.firstName[i];`? Besides that the structure looks pretty nonsensical. Also the rest of the code does.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Be nice - this was `char[]` yesterday! @Jannatul is progressing very rapidly.

Comment: Although @Jannatul when you've got the whole thing working, you could helpfully edit your question so the only error is the missing `istream& readAthlete` function or `operator>>` overload :) This way your question is more useful to other users in the future.

Comment: @JackDeeth I'm always nice. Isn't telling someone the truth considered _nice_ anymore?

Comment: Thank you @Jack! I'll definitely do that once I figure out how the code will work exactly :)

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your attempt. Firstly your struct

```
struct AthleteType {
    string firstName[SIZE];
    string lastName[SIZE];
    int athleteNumber[SIZE];
    string country[SIZE];
    int athleteTime[SIZE]; 
};
```

Your compiler error is telling you that you can't read into an array of strings, inputData >> firstName[SIZE];. One string at a time is fine of course.

If i peer into my crystal ball, I see that you want to store several athletes.  This should be done using a vector.

```
vector<Athlete> athletes;
```

And the struct can then be

```
struct Athlete
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int athleteNumber;
    string country;
    int athleteTime;
};
```

One athlete per object.

When reading from an input file you want to read based on read success.

```
   while(inputData >> athlete){  
       athletes.push_back(athlete); 
   }
```

You can do this by overloading `operator>> (istream&, Athlete& );`  or you can write a function that does a similar job.

```
istream& readAthlete(istream& in, Athlete& at){
    return in >> at.firstName >> at.lastName >> at.athleteNumber >> ... and so on;
}
```

Now the read function can be written as

```
vector<Athlete> readInput(string filename){
    vector<Athlete> athletes;
    ifstream inputData(filename);
    Athlete athlete;
    while(readAthlete(inputData, athlete)){
        athletes.push_back(athlete);
    }
    return athletes;
}
```

This is not tested code, it might work, it might not work, but it should give you a reasonable path forward.